# Unable to move box with margins or leftxx

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css and managed to whip up a site in a few days, while in the process I came upon this problem - im unable to move it to the center, I have tried using `left: 50%;` and still nothing. I am trying to move the entire contact back including the title to the center to put it in short.
[Example]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fVN4.jpg

I was unable to put the html and css script it in as it said it was spam so here it is on pastebin:

HTML: https://pastebin.com/Cs7Cui7h

CSS: https://pastebin.com/LBS7QrWf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
transform:translateX(-50%);
```

To the element that you want to be in the middle.

It is not showing in the middle because `left: 50%;` places the element 50% left from your left side of your screen. So that is not in the middle indeed.

When adding: `transform: translateX(-50%);` to the element that you need to be in the middle, it takes half of the width from that element and placing it in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

or

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

or create a parent div and add style for it

```
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```